The timing of publishing for domain events using Mediatr
I can't see why doing a savechanges interceptor to fire off the domain events is helpful or what it adds to an architecture as opposed to just publishing (eg await _mediator.Publish(domainEvent)) them from within the handler?



Centralises where events are raised and removes the requirement for coders to remember to do so?

coders still need to remember to add the domain event..... so it's centralizing where events are published but why am I excited about that?

What if you swap out the event provider, or want to alter the logic that happens before or after some events?  In your sample it doesn’t provide any benefit and likely just adds complexity, confusion  and overhead as the interceptor will run each time a change is made.
